# Removed Images from ArrayList are still showing

Tags: java, image, arraylist, javafx

I am working on a 2D game in which sprites for player are stored in array list. Since player has multiple states, I want to remove previous states upon use. I have an ArrayList as:

```
List<Image> x = new ArrayList();
```

Now I use images from this list as: `someImageView.setImage(x.getImage(y));`

And I remove first (say 5: `0,1,2,3,4,5`th images) states as:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    x.remove(y);
```

But these images still show instead of the next image set.

Could it be some sort of Caching? If so how can I delete this cache so my new images are applied?

My sprite images declaration is as follows (shown for one image, but its similar for all images):

```
Image someImg = new Image("path", true, false, true);
```

Comment: Did you call someImageView.setImage and rest the images after you removed them from the list?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether I understand you properly.

So, you use e.g. the first element of a list to be set on an `ImageView` (it is set properly), then you remove this element from the list.

At this point do you expect that the image will be removed from the `ImageView` also?

Why is shall be removed?

The list contains references to objects (pointers). When you set an image from the list the reference is passed to the ImageView, so now it will also point to that object. If you remove the reference from the list, it does not matter, the `ImageView` will still point to that reference.

So you can call `setImage` explicitly after you removed the elements, or use an `ObservableList` and set the image on remove (something like this):

```
ObservableList<Image> iList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
iList.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Image>()
{
    @Override
    public void onChanged(javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Image> change) {
        while(change.next())
        {
            if(change.wasRemoved())
                imgView.setImage(iList.get(0));
        }
    });
}
```